# Get a list of dynamic properties with an NDB Expando Model?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

With db it appears it was myexpando.dynamic_properties(), but trying to do that in ndb I get an AttributeError for dynamic_properties.

Can't find anything in the docs about a change to this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are using ndb you should be using _properties to get the list of properties

```
    The db, ndb, users, urlfetch, and memcache modules are imported.
dev~cash-drawer> class X(ndb.Expando):
...    pass
... 
dev~cash-drawer> 
dev~cash-drawer> 
dev~cash-drawer> y = X()
dev~cash-drawer> y.a = ndb.GenericProperty()
dev~cash-drawer> y.a = 100
dev~cash-drawer> y.a
100
dev~cash-drawer> repr(y.a)
'100'
dev~cash-drawer> type(y.a)
<type 'int'>
dev~cash-drawer> y._properties
{'a': GenericProperty('a')}
dev~cash-drawer>
```

See docs  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entities#expando

Comment: I've added to the NDB cheat sheet: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1AefylbadN456_Z7BZOpZEXDq8cR8LYu7QgI7bt5V0Iw/edit?pli=1

Comment: Ah. So I have to filter out the dynamic properties myself then?